# How to tighten the scope when using C++ lock_guard?

Tags: c++, locking, std, mutex, raii

In C++, `lock_guard` allows you to be RAII compliant when using locks. It calls `lock()` when constructing the `lock_guard`, and `unlock()` when destroying it once it goes out of scope.

Is it possible to tighten the scope of `lock_guard` such that it is destroyed sooner, to avoid keeping the lock for longer than necessary?

Comment: Did you try to use a set of closing braces around just the code you want the lock active on. Or alternatively, use a `std::unique_lock` and fire `unlock()`.

Comment: no, but that seems to work. I didn't know about using {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but you can introduce a block scope for the `std::lock_guard` with curly braces like this:

```
void foo()
{
    // do uncritical stuff

    { 
        // critical part starts here with construction
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> myLock(someMutex);

        // do critical stuff
    } // critical parts end here with myLock going out of scope

    // do uncritical stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `unique_lock` guard can be used instead of `lock_guard`. `unique_lock` gives you same RAII guarantees as `lock_guard` (calls `lock()` when constructing the lock_guard, and `unlock()` when destroying), as well as exposing `lock()` and `unlock()` to allow the you to lock and unlock yourself.

With a `unique_lock` you can `lock()` before the critical path, and `unlock()` straight after.

`unique_lock` will only call `unlock()` in the destructor if the lock was previously acquired, therefore there's no risk of releasing the lock twice (which causes undefined behavior).